# Binance OHLCV data showing incorrect Low or High Data

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner who is learning how to code a trading bot for Binance and come across a youtube video about supertrends in "Part Time Larry"'s channel, so I was following him while he is explaining the code and manage to duplicate his code. But I notice that the low and high prices are showing "1000" in some timestamps and obviously it is not right

here is my code:

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd
import config

exchange = ccxt.binance(dict(apiKey=config.Testnet_API_KEY, secret=config.Testnet_SECRET_KEY))
exchange.set_sandbox_mode(True)

balance = exchange.fetch_balance()
print(balance)

# ------Fetching Open high low close volume data from binance------
bars = exchange.fetchOHLCV("ETHUSDT")

# ------Changing the format into a usable table using pandas------
df = pd.DataFrame(bars[:-1], columns=["timestamp", 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
# ------Creating and appending a new column called previous close------
df['previousClose'] = df['close'].shift(1) # previous close value is the close value downshifted 1 row
# ------Creating and appending a new column called High-Low------

print(df)
```

The results become something like this:

| index | timestamp | open | high | Low | close | volume | previousClose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-02-14 04:39:00 | 2860.92 | 2861.87 | 2860.92 | 2861.57 | 3.75343 | NaN |
| 1 | 2022-02-14 04:40:00 | 2861.67 | 2861.93 | 2859.77 | 2861.93 | 4.20490 | 2861.57 |
| 2 | 2022-02-14 04:41:00 | 2861.67 | 2863.29 | 2861.42 | 2861.57 | 4.40562 | 2861.93 |
| 3 | 2022-02-14 04:42:00 | 2860.38 | 2862.24 | 2860.38 | 2862.24 | 3.22865 | 2861.57 |
| 4 | 2022-02-14 04:43:00 | 2862.41 | 2862.99 | 2861.44 | 2862.43 | 3.90235 | 2862.24 |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 494 | 2022-02-14 12:53:00 | 2903.41 | 2904.18 | 2903.41 | 2904.18 | 1.06401 | 2903.16 |
| 495 | 2022-02-14 12:54:00 | 2890.83 | 2911.21 | 1000.00 | 2911.21 | 3.35030 | 2904.18 |
| 496 | 2022-02-14 12:55:00 | 2911.21 | 2911.21 | 2907.39 | 2907.39 | 1.30982 | 2911.21 |
| 497 | 2022-02-14 12:56:00 | 2907.06 | 2908.94 | 2907.06 | 2908.94 | 1.54042 | 2907.39 |
| 498 | 2022-02-14 12:57:00 | 2909.08 | 2912.56 | 1000.00 | 2912.56 | 4.75237 | 2908.94 |

as you can see, the low price on the most recent bar and the 495th shows 1000, I tried to limit the amount of value the table is going to give and try to change the timeframe like this:

```
bars = exchange.fetchOHLCV("ETHUSDT", limit=5, timeframe="15m")
```

and it becomes worse
|index|timestamp|open|high|Low|close|volume|previousClose|
|:-----|:---------:|:----:|:----:|:---:|:-----:|:------:|-------------:|
|0|2022-02-14 12:15:00  |2864.85  |2934.51  |1000.00  |2867.61  |110.12610        |NaN|
|1|2022-02-14 12:30:00  |2867.68  |2929.21  |1000.00  |2903.62  |138.31086        |2867.61|
|2|2022-02-14 12:45:00  |2903.94  |2955.84  |1000.00  |2914.20   |77.76983        |2903.62|
|3 |2022-02-14 13:00:00  |2911.73  |2931.38  |2895.76  |2906.50   |69.45338        |2914.20|

is it my code's fault or did I import the wrong data?
Thanks

Comment: okay, I notice that the last table is a bit wonky, I am not sure how to fix it though, but to summarized the table, the 0th, 1st, and 2nd index's low is 1000